# JSON String to JSON Object in java

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my JSON String

```
"[{"name":"3214657890RootSAPSSE","children":[{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative"},{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão"}]}]"
```

When I parse it to json object in java I get null. This Field is coming from HTML hidden field where it is coming from java script.

Here is my java code

```
String x = request.getParameter("JSONString");
System.out.println(x);
        JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(x);
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType();
        List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toJSONString(), type);
        System.out.println(l.get(0).getName());
```

Here is my Java Class

```
public  class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    private List<EmployeeJSONObj> children = new LinkedList<>();
    EmployeeJSONObj()
    {

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", children = " + children;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using two different JSON parsing libraries?

Comment: I just ran your code and it works fine. Are you sure the json in `x` is the same as the one you posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't double-parse the string like that; it doesn't make sense to do so. Pass `x` directly to GSON.

```
String x = request.getParameter("JSONString");
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType();
List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(x, type);
System.out.println(l.get(0).getName());
```

Comment: I tried it before it did not work. When I print this string and pass to GSON it goes fine but as soon as I pass x it gives me different errors. Stuck in it from last 4hrs and I don't know what is the problem with my code

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what those errors are.

Comment: This is the error I get "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2"

Comment: Ah. So the actual JSON text starts with a `"` character? Why? Could you add to your question **exactly** what the `System.out.println` line prints in the console?

Comment: "[{"name":"3214657890RootSAPSSE","children":[{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative"},{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão"}]}]" This is the exact string it is printing on console

Comment: @user2777070 That's not valid JSON. Strip the leading and ending `"` or fix the JSON being written to the hidden input field.

Comment: Thanks man perfect - Great thanks. I was adding quotes in java script which was causing problem and I didn't even think about to look JS file. I was spending hours here on JAVA file , playing with Java Strings. Great thanks again.

Comment: @user2777070 you can sanity check your JSON at http://jsonlint.org. Happy coding!